# could not find function "pipeline" in R

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, pipeline

I have installed and loaded all of the tidyverse libraries which should include the 'pipeline' function in dplyr. When I try and run the following command:

```
data_frame_list = pipeline(input_file= file_name, input_list = data_frame_list
```

I get a traceback error:

> 'error in pipeline: could not find function 'pipeline'

I have loaded and installed all of the tidyverse packages and am in R version 4.2.

Comment: There is no function `pipeline` in `dplyr`. The pipe is `%>%` and comes from `magrittr` package. Also, why did you add a `jupyter` tag?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no such function `pipeline` in the tidyverse collection.

Comment: Can you include a link to the documentation describing `pipeline` in `dplyr`? Might be a version problem. Doesn't seem to be in the version of `dplyr` I have installed.

Comment: I also have loaded the Magrittr package but it still not working

Comment: it says part of the R package, https://www.R-project.org

Comment: I can go into he folder and see all of the commands in the Magrittr package and it does not seem to be present. Will I need to return to the older version of R?